# Baldur's Gate 2: Drogomir's Tomb

Tags: baldurs-gate-2, baldurs-gate-2-enhanced

I've been playing Baldur's Gate 2: The Enhanced Edition as an Archer. My party consists of 2 Fighters, 1 Druid, 1 Archer and a Cleric. While doing the Drogomir's tomb quest line, I'm having difficulty in defeating Drogomir himself.

All my weapons are completely ineffective against him and the only way I was able to chip away his health was by casting Magic Missile on him by the Cleric. The rest of my party is completely useless.

Are there any ways to defeat him by using my present party?

I don't want any more spellcasters in my group.

I'm completely new to this game and some pointers would prove helpful.

Comment: I don't remember this fight, but it sounds like you'll need magic (+2 etc.) weapons to even be able to hurt him.

Comment: How can I get those?

Comment: The game is an open world. You need to explore and come back later if the current dungeon is too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to multiple posts on the Beamdog [forums](https://forums.beamdog.com/discussion/62140/how-to-defeat-dragomir), Dagomir has resistance to non-magical weapons. You've essentially confirmed this, by hurting him with a spell but no melee attacks.

You'll need at least +2 weapons, to be able to even injure him. According to a [thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/257350/discussions/0/412448792356284487/) on Steam, you should be able to buy some at the Copper Coronet. You may also be able to "create" magic weapons using the spell [Enchanted Weapon](https://baldursgate.fandom.com/wiki/Enchanted_Weapon).

Comment: Will using +2 Arrows work?

Comment: @SlayerDiAngelo, I think so.  I'm fairly sure the "is it magical?" check is based on the projectile, not the launcher.

Comment: Thanks, using arrows (+2) worked; the same goes for bullets and darts too